# How many combinations of winners will there be?

Tags: combinatorics

> In a weight-lifting competition, there are 3 Americans, 4 Russians, 2 Chinese, and 1 Canadian. How many outcomes will there be such that 1 American is among the top three and 2 Americans will be among the bottom three?

What I said was that, because there is only one American in the first three, then I must choose two other competitors from seven in order to fill out the other two slots $\binom{7}{2}$. I must do the same thing for the bottom slot not filled out by the Americans yet, therefore I get $\binom{5}{1}$. Multiplying both of them by three (for the different permutations of the places among themselves) I get $$9\binom{7}{2} \binom{5}{1} = 945$$ Which according to the book is the correct answer, but what happened to the other four slots? Should I not multiply that final answer by $4!$ to get the actual outcome? How else might I do this problem?

Comment: If the ranks in between the first and the last positions matter, then you should multiply by 4!

Comment: That is what I was thinking but my book says that $945$ is the answer. Do those ranks not matter when counting the outcomes?

Comment: But you haven't chosen the american who will be first, (3 ways) and you're wrong in multiplying by 9 because the second and third slots can be filled in 2! ways and similarly the bottom two also in 2! ways, the middle ones in 4! Ways. In total this gives 30240 ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, only  **nationalities** are to be considered, not individuals (strange though it is !)

[May be, just like medal counts in the Olympics, where only countries figure in the tallies ! ]

The $3$ Americans can be positioned in $\binom31\binom32$ = 9 ways,
and the rest positioned in $\dfrac{7!}{4!2!1!}$ ways.

Multiply the two to get the ans of $\;945$